# In Harry Potter where do Honoria Dumbledore and Araminta Meliflua Black fit on a family tree?

Tags: harry-potter, character-identification

I have written a family tree for Harry Potter but don't know where Honoria Dumbledore and Araminta Meliflua Black go - any suggestions?

Comment: Er... Who? Where did you find these names? What is the context of these people? Where *should* they be on the tree?

Comment: Araminta Meliflua Black is mentioned by Sirius as an aunt of his mother’s who tried to make Muggle Hunting legal and Honoria Dumbledore is mentioned in the Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them book as Dumbledore's maternal aunt

Comment: Is that not then the answer to your question? They are both sisters of the respective mothers.

Comment: Firstly, with Araminta Meliflua Black no because she is an aunt of his mothers and that could be any of several and secondly I was not sure what maternal aunt means (does it mean sister of a mother)

Comment: Ah, "aunt of mother". I misread that. Yes, "maternal aunt" means aunt on the mother's side of the family. So that would either be a sister or sister-in-law of the mother.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Honoria Dumbledore

Honoria is an aunt of Albus, Aberforth, and Ariana Dumbledore. It's **unknown** whether she's an aunt on their mother's side or their father's. From [HP Lexicon](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/dumbledore-family/honoria/):

> Honoria was the aunt of Albus Dumbledore. He referred to her as his “maiden aunt.” [...] It is unknown whether Honoria is Kendra's sister or Percival's. Even though Kendra is a Muggle-born, there is precedent for Muggle-born siblings both having magic (like the Creeveys).

See also [this talk page](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Honoria) for more speculation and evidence supporting her being Percival's sister, but nothing really certain. There's also a Harry Potter Family Trees Wikia (because of course there is) with [this page](http://harrypotterfamilytrees.wikia.com/wiki/Dumbledore_Family_Tree) listing the known Dumbledores, but again no info about which side of the family is Honoria's.

### Araminta Meliflua Black

Again we don't know her exact position in the family tree, only that she was a cousin of Sirius and Regulus's mother. From [HP Lexicon](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/character/black-family/araminta-meliflua/):

> Appears on the Black Family Tree; cousin of Walburga Black.

However, in this case we have a *little* more information because JK Rowling has actually drawn a canonical Black Family Tree. I found it from [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/108109/31394); image reproduced here:

[image: family tree]

So we can speculate that Araminta Melliflua might be the daughter of Callidora and Harfang Longbottom, or of Charis and Caspar Crouch (either of which would put her in the same generation as Walpurga, as a second cousin). But again, this is speculation and we don't know for certain.

Comment: Oh my gosh a Black family tree!! :D

Comment: Honoria is obviously from Albus' father's side otherwise her patronym would not be Dumbledore

Comment: @dounyy Is she actually referred to as Honoria Dumbledore in canon, or is she just Albus Dumbledore's aunt Honoria and people assumed her surname was Dumbledore too?

Comment: @Randal'Thor you are right, the head title of this answer mislead me. Only her first name is known.